# I want to insert the information obtained from the spreadsheet into the dialog using GAS and HTML into the initial value of the text field

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets, google-apps-script, spreadsheet

It is possible to retrieve information entered into cells in a spreadsheet.
Next, how can we insert the information obtained in HTML into a text field as an initial value?
I have created it so far, but I am not able to dynamically insert a value into the initial value.

```
function onRemoveOrEditButton() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  const initialValue = sheet.getRange("A1").getValue();
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Dialog').setWidth(300);
  htmlOutput.append('<script>var initialValue = ' + JSON.stringify(initialValue) + ';</script>');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, ' ');
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/@primer/css@^20.2.4/dist/primer.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <style>
      .form-control {
        width: 200px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
      <input class="form-control input-block" type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="name" style="width: 300px;" value= "<?= initialValue ?>"><br>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your expected result as follows?

#### Google Apps Script:

```js
function onRemoveOrEditButton() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  const initialValue = sheet.getRange("A1").getValue();
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Dialog');
  html.initialValue = JSON.stringify(initialValue);
  html.sampleScript = `<script>var initialValue = ${JSON.stringify(initialValue)};console.log(initialValue);</script>`;
  var htmlOutput = html.evaluate().setWidth(300);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, ' ');
}
```

#### HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/@primer/css@^20.2.4/dist/primer.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <style>
      .form-control {
        width: 200px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
      <input class="form-control input-block" type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="name" style="width: 300px;" value= <?!= initialValue ?>><br>
      <?!= sampleScript ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

- When you run the function `onRemoveOrEditButton`, a dialog is opened on the Spreadsheet. The cell value of "A1" of the active sheet is shown in the input tag. Also, you can see the value of `initialValue` in the console.

#### Reference:

- [HTML Service: Templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)